# Is "audience" singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, collective-nouns

I want to use 'audience' in the following sentence. In what form should I use it? Is it a singular or plural noun?

> How the audience *demotivate* players in the NBA.
>
> How the audience *demotivates* players in the NBA.

Comment: audience is a collective noun with a plural: audiences.

Comment: I think your title is rather misleading. I had to delete my answer.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a new title?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Singular if you want to emphasise its homogeneity, plural if you want to emphasise its component parts.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar: 1. The audience was united in its appreciation of the concert. 2. The audience were divided in their appreciation of the concert.

Comment: 'Audience' as a plural sounds really off. I don't think it is accepted AmE usage.

Comment: "The audience are clapping their hands" sounds right to me. "The audience is huge" seems to have a different meaning from "The audience are huge".

Comment: If the speaker wanted to emphasize the members of the set, he could use "The people in the audience were..." or maybe more specifically "The male members of the audience were...". But maybe I'm in scientific mode where I'm wrongfully arguing against common practice, be it logical or not...

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, BrEng seems to be more comfortable than AmEng with words having plural agreement, when they look singular.

Comment: @Mitch: You’re exactly right. Any American proofreader would reflexively swap a plural verb to match the singular ‘noun of multitude’, because it is ungrammatical in standard American English to write *‘An audience ***are** expected to applaud’* instead of *‘An audience **is** expected to applaud’*, and changing the article from indefinite to definite does not alter the required concordance. [This style sheet for authors](http://oreilly.com/oreilly/author/stylesheet.html) makes this matter perfectly clear.

Comment: I'd tend to change it to 'the audience applauded'. There's always an alternative way in which to phrase something.Glad that AmEng adheres to what makes good sense, sad that BrEng, which I taught, appears to eschew it.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, So how does this match with the answer at http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58717/8278 ? Who is right?

Comment: IMHO, this answer is not at all helpful to a non-native speaker without the example in the second comment. It should really be amended to include that example. Sacrificing complete understanding of meaning for clever brevity of words is not so smart imho.

Answer (score 21):

Ooh, I learned something today: American and British English apparently differ on this.

From Grammar Girl (which I understand is an even more authoritative source than pop song lyrics):

> Americans tend to treat collective nouns as single units, so it’s more
>   common to use the singular verb unless you’re definitely talking about
>   individuals (3). So in America you would be more likely to hear “The
>   faculty is meeting today” than “The faculty are meeting today.”   In
>   British usage, however, it’s the opposite; it’s more common to use the
>   plural verb (4). In fact, some sentences that are perfectly correct in
>   Britain would be considered incorrect in America (3). Take “Cambridge
>   are winning the boat race.” Although I spent my elementary-school
>   years in London, I have been fully Americanized, so this sentence
>   doesn’t sound right to me. As an American, I would say, “Cambridge is
>   winning.”

[http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/collective-nouns.aspx]

When I was in school I was taught that collective nouns always take a singular.

The ever-popular Google Ngram shows "audience is" far more common than "audience are".
http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=audience+is%2Caudience+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Of course a collective noun can be pluralized: You can say, "Of the three audiences we have had at our concerts, one audience booed us off the stage and two audiences threw rocks." Just like "committee" is a collective noun, but it's quite reasonable to say, "Two new committees were formed yesterday."

Comment: In google ngrams, you can choose a British corpus or an American corpus to see the difference.

Comment: +1 for 'even more authoritative source than pop song lyrics'

Comment: Great answer.  How ironic that the Brits don't speak proper english!  :-p

Answer (score 8):

It's a singular noun that represents a set of people, so I would use

> How the audience demotivates players

but

> How the people in the audience demotivate players

Comment: This example is **irrelevant** because `demotivate` is not matched with `audience` but matched with `people`.

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct. *[Audience](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/audience_1)* may be used with a singular or plural verb.

Comment: Not in America it cannot. A plural verb are going to sound wrong here to the American ear, and will be quickly corrected by any proofreader who gets their hands on it.

Answer (score 2):

*Audience* is a **collective noun**. If you think and/or express it as **a group** it is singular; If you think and/or express it as **individuals acting within the whole** it is  plural.

Comment: Perhaps in Olde Englande, but not Stateside.