# usage of 'its' in sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is audience singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58692/is-audience-singular-or-plural)

> During the final minutes of his speech,the speaker requested the audience to hold *its* applause.

Is the usage of 'its' correct in the sentence. Should it be replaced with 'their' ?

I am not sure of using 'its' because, the audience are not inanimate(like stones).

Comment: *Their* can be used to refer to stones, too. So the distinction between *its* vs. *their* is not one between inanimate vs. animate. It's a question of whether you regard the audience as singular or plural. Which is covered in the linked question.