# Difference between audience and audiences?

Tags: differences, word-usage

I've heard some people say the word *audiences* in conversation. How does *audiences* differ from *audience* and when do you use it?

Comment: First, look up the word in an online dictionary. If the meaning is still unclear between *audience* and *audiences* then you can edit your post and ask for clarification, explaining why you are confused. This is a "general reference" question. You're on the Internet, use it.

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58692/is-audience-singular-or-plural

Comment: @Mari-LouA I did that before I was posting here.I wasn't clear with examples which had been given there.

Comment: @PraveenKadambari you can edit your question, include the examples which confused you and say *why* you haven't got the gist of things. It's perfectly fine to ask these type of questions, but we can't possibly know "why" you are having difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

Audience is a single group of people that are participating in watching a performance. Audiences is more than one group watching a performances: e.g., Audiences around the world enjoyed the stunning performance of the recent online musical. If you want to talk about plurals within a single audience, you can say audience members.