# People who is or People who are

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I want to know if which one is correct, for example I want to say: "The people who is in charge of this process" or "The people who are in charge of this process". I'm a bit confused because of the "who" word in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: [How to use "who" vs. "that"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11204) asks when to use either of who or that for plural subjects and singular subjects, which subsumes the present question, but doesn't answer it. Also see [Does “the same number of people” behave as singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/63398) and   [Should I say “there is a handful of ...” or “there are a handful of ...”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58676)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you would say "The people who are in charge of the process". Here, 'people' is plural, and refers to a group of more than one person, hence the use of 'are', rather than 'is'.

If just one person were in charge, you would say "The person who is in charge of the process".

Comment: But 'population', is usually singular. 'The population of the United Kingdom is about 61 million'. But 'electorate' can be either singular or plural. 'The electorate is divided on the issue'. 'The electorate are literate and politically aware'.

Answer (score 2):

ARE  is the right one. basically because it refers to a group of individuals rather than a community labeled under a name.